why wont my C socket created using a custom protocol bind?
All the other code is able to work, like assigning the protocol, hardware type, etc to sockaddr_ll, but the second I try to bind it, it gives me an error.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if_arp.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <libcap.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RCP             49152
#define ARPHRD_ETHER    1
#define PACKET_RX       2
#define sizepkt         512
typedef unsigned short ushort_t;
struct sockaddr_ll {
    ushort_t sll_family;      /* address family (AF_LINK) */
    ushort_t sll_protocol;    /* link-layer protocol (e.g., Ethernet) */
    int32_t sll_ifindex;      /* interface index */
    uint16_t sll_hatype;     /* ARP hardware type */
    uint8_t  sll_pkttype;    /* packet type */
    uint8_t  sll_halen;      /* hardware address length */
    uint8_t  sll_addr[8];   /* hardware address (e.g., MAC address) */
};

uint16_t srcport;
uint16_t extport;
uint16_t srcport1;
uint16_t extport2;
char payload[256];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int intextport = atoi(argv[1]);
    cap_t caps = cap_init();
        cap_value_t *capvl = 0;
            cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_NET_RAW, 1, capvl, CAP_SET);
int sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, RCP);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    printf("Socket not created\n");
    printf("%d\n", sockfd);
    return -1;
    } else {
        printf("Socket Created successfully\n");
    }
    printf("test1\n");
    struct sockaddr_in *dst_addr = malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    printf("1\n");
    char buffer[sizepkt];
        printf("hi\n");
        dst_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
        printf("test2\n");
        dst_addr->sin_port = htons(intextport);
        printf("test3\n");
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &dst_addr->sin_addr);
        printf("test4\n");
        struct sockaddr_ll *src_addr = malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        int error1 = src_addr->sll_family = AF_PACKET;
                if (error1 < 0) {
            printf("socket family couldn't be set\n");
            printf("%d\n", error1);
            return -1;
        }
        int error2 = src_addr->sll_protocol = RCP;
                if (error2 < 0) {
            printf("The Internet protocol(IP) couldn't be set up\n");
            printf("%d\n", error2);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("test5\n");
        int error3 = src_addr->sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("wlan0");
                if (error3 < 0) {
            printf("local interface couldn't be set up\n");
            printf("%d\n", error3);
            return -1;
        }
        int error4 = src_addr->sll_pkttype = PACKET_RX;
                if (error4 < 0) {
            printf("package type couldn't be set\n");
            printf("%d\n", error4);
            return -1;
        }
        int error5 = src_addr->sll_halen = 6;
                        if (error5 < 0) {
            printf("package type couldn't be set\n");
            printf("%d\n", error5);
            return -1;
        }
        int error6 = src_addr->sll_hatype = ARPHRD_ETHER;
                        if (error6 < 0) {
            printf("package type couldn't be set\n");
            printf("%d\n", error6);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("test6\n");
        struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr;
        printf("1\n");
        struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr;
     strcpy(payload, "This packet was sent using RCPing under the Really Crappy Protocol");
     extport = htons(intextport);
     srcport = htons(RCP);
     char chrsrcport[16];
     char chrextport[16];
     sprintf(chrsrcport, "%d", srcport);
     sprintf(chrextport, "%d", extport);
        memcpy(buffer, chrsrcport, sizeof(chrsrcport));
        printf("7\n");
            memcpy(buffer + sizeof(chrsrcport), chrextport, sizeof(chrextport));
            printf("8\n");
                memcpy(buffer + sizeof(chrsrcport) + sizeof(chrextport), payload, 8);
                printf("9\n");
        srcport1 = htons(RCP);
        extport2 = htons(intextport);
        int miku = bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(interlcal));
        printf("10\n");
        if (miku < 0) {
            printf("client interface couldn't be set up\n");
            printf("%d\n", miku);
            return -1;
        }

        int jumanji = connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (jumanji < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't establish a connection using RCP, unsurprisingly\n");
        printf("%d", jumanji);
        return -1;
    } else {
        while (main) {
            ssize_t senresult = send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if (senresult < 0) {
                printf("Package wasn't sent");
            }
        }
    }
}

Ignore the random printf statements. I was using those because it was giving me segfaults, and I was trying to track down the line that was causing it.
command I used to compile it:
gcc rcping.c -o rcping -lcap

Isn't <libcap.h> an internal header for libcap? Shouldn't you use <sys/capability.h>?

"ignore the random printf statements [...]" -- well no, that's not how it works here.  We expect you to put in the work to narrow your code to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.  It might be that some of the printf calls would actually useful in such an MRE, but you're the one looking for answers, so it's to your advantage to make it easier for us to provide them.  Plus, it looks like that would involve a lot more than just removing some print statements.

Or alternatively, @IanAbbott, I might be inclined to say bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(*interlcal));.

struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr; should be struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)dst_addr;. struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr; should be struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)src_addr;. bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(interlcal)); should be bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(*src_addr));. connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(addr)); should be connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(*dst_addr));.

@IanAbbott that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Aside: Try to format your code sensibly. I'm getting a headache trying to read that. If that's how your code is actually formatted, no wonder you're having problems. It's 2024, most editors will format your code for you as you type it in.

As Ian said in this comment:

struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr;
should be:
struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)dst_addr;

struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr;
should be
struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)src_addr

bind(sockfd, interlcal,  sizeof(interlcal));
should be:
bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(*src_addr));

(note: this didn't work but the binding one did)
connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(addr));
should be
connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(*dst_addr));


Just adding this so I can help others see this more easily, and so this question can be answered.
